# javascript/php simple drop down menu logout

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, logout

to save space, I would like to consolidate the username and logut buttons at the top of web template into one link.  The username would be visible and when you hover over it as in stack overflow or click as in gmail or fb, you have option to logout or do other account related things.  Ideally, would like to do this in css or javascript without jquery overhead.

Can anyone recommend simple javascript or other technique as I am very inexperienced in javascript.  Don't need complicated full blown drop down menu.  It should be something like below, but below is unpredictable...shows menu when page loads etc.  Thx.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
showMenu = function() {
var div = document.getElementById('box1');
div.style.display = 'block';
    }
hideMenu = function() {
var div = document.getElementById('box1');
div.style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
        <td onmouseover="showMenu()" >username</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="box1" onmouseout="hideMenu()">
    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a><br>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE- this should fix the "jumping" problem:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .username {
                width: 100px;
                border: 1px solid #ff0000;
                padding: 3px;
                text-align: center;
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            #box1 {
                display: none;
                text-align: center;
                position: absolute;
                background-color: #ccc;
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            showMenu = function() {
                var div = document.getElementById('box1');
                div.style.display = 'block';
            }
            hideMenu = function() {
                var div = document.getElementById('box1');
                div.style.display = 'none';
            }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=3 align="left">
                <img src=":">
            </td>

            <td colspan=6 valign="bottom" align="right">Menu1 Menu2 Menu3 Menu4 Menu5 Menu6 Menu7
                <div class="username" onmouseover="showMenu();" onmouseout="hideMenu();">Username
                    <span id="box1">
                        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan=9>
                <hr color="red">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that absolute positioning doesn't work the same inside of a span than as it does a div. So I had to change the "username" span to a div and use absolute position for the "box1" span. You could even change the "box1" span to a div as well so it occupies the whole width possible of the "username" div. Let me know how this one goes!

Comment: This close to does it.  The div tag added a line break so I replaced it with a span.  And the userid is part of a larger top menu so the formatting is fine.  The only issue is on the mouseover event, instead of the logout link dropping down, the userid (and whole line of text it is part of jumps up).  If it went down the dropdown would cover the line below... but I would prefer that to the userid text jumping up.  Any way to control how the dropdown occurs?

Comment: I just put position: absolute; back in(I'd taken formatting out) and it now drops down nicely, but at beginning, the whole line is shifted to the right beyond columns below...guessing solution lies in formatting of style tag.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Would you mind providing what you have for this section of HTML now?

Comment: I just edited this answer, instead of making another or something else :)

Comment: Many thx!  The display: inline-block; did it.  On a related matter do you know a script to show hide/text using a link inside the text to be hidden as in stackoverflow.com/questions/10066047/javascript-swap-text-block-onclick-anchor-link?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the version where it jumps up.  If you put position: absolute;  in the style tag the menu extends one more cell to the right past the other columns...
    
    
        
            .username {
                }

```
        #box1 {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        showMenu = function() {
            var div = document.getElementById('box1');
            div.style.display = 'block';
        }
        hideMenu = function() {
            var div = document.getElementById('box1');
            div.style.display = 'none';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table><tr>

<td colspan=3 align="left"><img src=":"></td>
<td colspan=6 valign="bottom" align="right">Menu1 Menu2 Menu3 Menu4 Menu5 

Menu6 Menu7 <span class="username" onmouseover="showMenu();" 

onmouseout="hideMenu();">Username<span id="box1">
                        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
                    </span>
                </span></b></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=9><hr color = "red"></td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: placing position:relative; in outer tag and position:relative in dropdown stopped jumping.  However, menu is now dropping down not below link but at far left of page...seems solution is in javacript formatting.